# How do I fetch table with attributes using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

How can I fetch table with other attributes using beautifulSoup?

I have this table :
[image]

I have tried this but didn't succeed :

```
Soup.find_all('table',{'style':"width=100%;align:center;border:0;cellpadding:0;cellspacing:0"})
```

Comment: Please provide what you have tried so far? What do you mean by _other attribute_?

Comment: Soup.find_all('table',{'style':"width=100%;align:center;border:0;cellpadding:0;cellspacing:0"})

Comment: Please write that in question, I have tried this but didn't succeed!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a full example of what you have already tried to by providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @davidalive is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68553961/12446721) what you're looking for?

Comment: @Xitiz Did you mean to tag OP instead of me? Also, this question appears all the time. I have voted to close it. And downvoted your answer. I hope you understand

Comment: @Xitiz You're right, the post I have linked to was a bit different (although it can still answer the question). And I have upvoted your answer (although this was addressed many times)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_source = '''
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<table width="100%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source, 'html.parser')

els = list(soup.find("table",attrs={"width":"100%","border":"0","align":"center"}))

print(' '.join(map(str, els)))
```

You can provide as many attributes as you want in that dictionary. You can get a bit more information from [here](https://pytutorial.com/beautifulsoup-attribute).

Example: https://www.napkin.io/n/c174e5c8557d402d

Comment: In link is there any information? And I think link is already broken

Comment: here's the link: https://www.napkin.io/n/c174e5c8557d402d. i made an edit as well :)